# Match spacing of align in array environment

Tags: math-mode, spacing, align

To typeset some displayed equations, only the `array` environment was powerful enough.  However, the spacing of the `array` environment doesn't match the spacing of the `align` environment.

How do I set the spacing of the `array` environment, such that equals the vertical spacing of the `align` environment.

For instance:

```
\begin{align*}
a & = b + c \\
d & = e + f
\end{align*}
```

and

```
\[\begin{array}{rl}
a & = b + c \\
d & = e + f
\end{array}\]
```

have different spacing.

Comment: `array` is not the right way to typeset equations (as you've discovered). You should instead ask how to typeset the particular equations you want typeset.

Comment: @TH. For the equation I wanted to set, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7730/multi-column-delimiter-in-align

Comment: **Note**: it's possible to customize the preamble of `alignat`, which is easier than tweaking `array` to match the spacing, see [equations - rcl column alignment, no extra spaces, and \tag{} for each line - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/381362/rcl-column-alignment-no-extra-spaces-and-tag-for-each-line/381402#381402)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
a & = b + c \\
d & = e + f
\end{align*}

\[
\begin{array}{rl}
a & = b + c \\
d & = e + f
\end{array}
\]

\arraycolsep=1.4pt
\def\arraystretch{1.2}
\[
\begin{array}{rl}
a & = b + c \\
d & = e + f
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: The horizontal space is now correct. Thanks. However, the vertical spacing still differs.  A propos: where did you find the 1.4pt?

Comment: see example with defining the array stretch

Comment: Thanks again!  The spacing is not exactly the same, though.  See http://img143.imageshack.us/img143/7700/aboutright.png  I've colored the {array} one red and moved it on top of the original {align*}.

Comment: It seems to work in the intended situation though.  ( See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7730/multi-column-delimiter-in-align )