# Multi-column delimiter in align

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, amsmath

I want to set the following, but with all the <'s aligned horizontally

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqeiG.png]

Source of this failed attempt:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\ra}{\rightarrow}
\newcommand{\T}[1]{\mathbb{T}_{#1}}
\newcommand{\lbe}{<_{\beta\eta}}

\begin{align*}
0 & \lbe 0 \ra 0                && \in \T0 \\
&\left.
\begin{aligned}
& \lbe 0^2 \ra 0 \\
& \lbe \cdots \\
& \lbe 0^k \ra 0 \\
& \lbe \cdots
\end{aligned}
\right\}                        && \in \T1 \\
& \lbe 1 \ra 0 \ra 0            && \in \T2 \\
& \lbe 1 \ra 1 \ra 0 \ra 0      && \in \T3 \\
& \lbe 3 \ra 0 \ra 0            && \in \T4 \\
& \lbe 1_2 \ra 0 \ra 0          && \in \T5
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I added your image inline. since you have 10 rep you should be able to edit your question with no problems due to the image...

Comment: The alignat environment will do that.  Part of amsmath.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\ra}{\rightarrow}
\newcommand{\T}[1]{\mathbb{T}_{#1}}
\newcommand{\lbe}{<_{\beta\eta}}

\begin{align*}
0 & \lbe 0 \ra 0                && \in \T0 \\
&\left.
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
\begin{array}{@{}l}
\lbe\displaystyle 0^2 \ra 0 \\
\lbe\displaystyle \cdots \\
\lbe\displaystyle 0^k \ra 0 \\
\lbe\displaystyle \cdots
\end{array}
\right\}                        && \in \T1 \\
& \lbe 1 \ra 0 \ra 0            && \in \T2 \\
& \lbe 1 \ra 1 \ra 0 \ra 0      && \in \T3 \\
& \lbe 3 \ra 0 \ra 0            && \in \T4 \\
& \lbe 1_2 \ra 0 \ra 0          && \in \T5
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

This is basically what the `cases` environment does except that it has two columns, the brace is on the other side and the `\arraystretch` is set to 1.2.

**Edit:**
This is basically how `aligned` works except that I removed the `\null\,`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{alignedleft}[1][c]{%
    \RIfM@\else
        \nonmatherr@{\begin{\@currenvir}}%
    \fi
    \if #1t\vtop \else \if#1b \vbox \else \vcenter \fi \fi \bgroup
        \def\math@cr@@@{\cr}%
        \Let@ \chardef\dspbrk@context\@ne
        \default@tag
        \spread@equation % no-op if already called
        \ialign\bgroup
           &\strut@
            $\m@th\displaystyle{##}$%
            \hfil
            \tabskip\minalignsep
            \crcr
}{%
    \crcr
    \egroup
    \egroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\ra}{\rightarrow}
\newcommand{\T}[1]{\mathbb{T}_{#1}}
\newcommand{\lbe}{<_{\beta\eta}}

\begin{align*}
0 & \lbe 0 \ra 0                && \in \T0 \\
&
\def\arraystretch{1.206}
\left.
\begin{alignedleft}
\lbe 0^2 \ra 0 \\
\lbe \cdots \\
\lbe 0^k \ra 0 \\
\lbe \cdots
\end{alignedleft}
\right\}                        && \in \T1 \\
& \lbe 1 \ra 0 \ra 0            && \in \T2 \\
& \lbe 1 \ra 1 \ra 0 \ra 0      && \in \T3 \\
& \lbe 3 \ra 0 \ra 0            && \in \T4 \\
& \lbe 1_2 \ra 0 \ra 0          && \in \T5
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks.  This method looks promising.  There are two imperfections: the spacing within the array is larger than outside of the array.  When setting <code>\arraystretch</code> to 1.2 instead of 1.3, that problem disappears.  The second problem is that the spacing between <code>0 \ra 0</code> and <code>0^2 \ra 0</code> _and_ <code>\cdots</code> and <code>1 \ra 0 \ra 0</code> is bigger than it should.

Comment: @bas: Actually, I think what you want is `1.2069` for a 12 pt document and 2.5 for a 10 pt document. (`align` uses `\openup\jot` with \jot set to 3 pt so what you really want is `1+3/\baselineskip` where `\baselineskip is 12 pt for a 10 pt document and 14.5 pt for a 12 pt document [I didn't look up what 11 pt was].) The extra space above and below the `array` comes from the brace.

Comment: @TH. Great!  Two questions: (1) Can I define the `\arraystretch' by using the used constants? (2) Can I get rid of the extra space above and below the `array' caused by the brace?

Comment: @bas: I provided another way of doing it that is very similar to `aligned`. Hopefully this does what you want.

Comment: @TH.  That's nice!  The only remaining glitch is the additional vertical space. Is there any way to get rid of it?

Comment: @bas: Which additional vertical space?

Comment: @TH I've added some rules to your version of 25 december which shows the vertical and horizontal spacing glitches.  PDF: http://w-nz.com/~bas/overflow/mcb1.pdf  Source: http://w-nz.com/~bas/overflow/mcb1.tex

Answer (score 1):

The `\hline` are only for some demonstration here. Should be deleted and for the last line of the `align`environment also the `\\`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand\ra{\rightarrow}
\newcommand\T[1]{\mathbb{T}_{#1}}
\newcommand\lbe{<_{\beta\eta}}
\begin{document}

\twocolumn
\begin{align*}
0 & \lbe 0 \ra 0                && \in \T0 \\\hline
  & \lbe 0^2 \ra 0 \\\hline
  & \lbe \cdots \\\hline
  & \lbe 0^k \ra 0 && \in \T1 \\\hline
  & \lbe \cdots\\\hline
  & \lbe 1 \ra 0 \ra 0            && \in \T2 \\\hline
  & \lbe 1 \ra 1 \ra 0 \ra 0      && \in \T3 \\\hline
  & \lbe 3 \ra 0 \ra 0            && \in \T4 \\\hline
  & \lbe 1_2 \ra 0 \ra 0          && \in \T5\\\hline
\end{align*}

\newpage

\begin{align*}
0 & \lbe 0 \ra 0                && \in \T0 \\\hline
  & \lbe 0^2 \ra 0 \\\hline
  & \lbe \cdots \\\hline
  & \lbe 0^k \ra 0 \quad
    \makebox(0,0){\put(0,60){$\left.\rule{0pt}{1.4cm}\right\}$}} 
         && \mathrel{\makebox(0,0){\put(0,30){$\in \T1$}}} \\\hline
  & \lbe \cdots\\\hline
  & \lbe 1 \ra 0 \ra 0            && \in \T2 \\\hline
  & \lbe 1 \ra 1 \ra 0 \ra 0      && \in \T3 \\\hline
  & \lbe 3 \ra 0 \ra 0            && \in \T4 \\\hline
  & \lbe 1_2 \ra 0 \ra 0          && \in \T5\\\hline
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks.  This almost perfectly sets the formulae.  There is one glitch:  the space beneath the first \cdots is too large.  I also have to ask whether your method can be made more general – viz. not having to manually set the 1.4cm, 60 and 30.

Comment: everything can be done automatically, but it is not worth to investigate here, when you need it oly for this one specific case

Comment: Two things:  (1) I intended using these _multicolumn delimiters_ in more places.  Besides that, it would be educational (for me) to see (pointers to) the general solution.  (2) Have you looked at the extra vertical space at the first '\cdots'?

Comment: I see no extra vertical space, see example

Comment: I don't see it in the updated answer anymore.  However, it remains in the first answer.  (Version 1)  See this image: http://img405.imageshack.us/img405/5987/screenshot20101226at244.png

Comment: sorry, can't see an extra vertical space in your image

Comment: I've added red boxes of equal height to the image.  You can find it here:  http://w-nz.com/~bas/overflow/mcb2.png