# rcl column alignment, no extra spaces, and \tag{} for each line

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, tag

I'm looking for a way to place some text flushed to the right margin (like `\tag*{…}` does) at the end of each line of an equation. The equation has multiple columns, and I need to control the alignment (right, center or left) of each column. Furthermore, I don't want the environment to add extra space before the first column, after the last column or between columns.

I tried the following, which does not work because only a single `\tag{…}` is allowed for the whole equation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{@{}r@{}c@{}l@{}}
  a&bbbbb&c \tag*{a, b and c} \\
  x&y&z    \tag*{other stuff}\\
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot of the desired outcome.]

It would be cool if I could also do this for sub-`cases` (lines after a big opening brace), like `numcases` does (but `numcases` does not support `\tag`, and adds extra spaces everywhere).

**Things I tried (after browsing through quite a few questions here):**

- `equationarray` from the `eqnarray` package looks promissing, but it does not support the `\tag{…}` command, only `\notag` (I tried and failed to manually call the internals of what `\tag{…}` does). `align` adds extra space between
- `align` and `empheq` do not support `rcl` column specifications and add extra space
- `alignat*` has everything except `rcl` column specification (it is hardcoded to be `rlrlrl…`)

Right now my best bet is to put a marker with `tikz` and draw the label as an overlay (I am not extremely interested in precise `\label`/`\ref` references, I can make all labels point to the whole multi-line equation if needed, so drawing with `tikz` is a crude, but viable solution).

Comment: I added a less hackish solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can abuse `IEEEtrantools` (but I recommend not pushing material that belongs in the equation to the right margin, which should be reserved for reference marks or numbers).

Note that you are responsible for avoding overlaps.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\begin{IEEEeqnarray*}{r-c-l+r-}
a&bbbbb&c &\makebox[0pt][r]{a, b and c} \\
x&y&z     &\makebox[0pt][r]{other stuff}
\end{IEEEeqnarray*}

\begin{equation}
abbbbbc
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Original answer for reference

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}

\renewcommand\theIEEEsubequationdis{\theIEEEsubequation}
\newcommand{\IEEEtag}[1]{%
  \IEEEyessubnumber
  \gdef\theIEEEsubequation{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{r-c-l}
a&bbbbb&c \IEEEtag{a, b and c} \\
x&y&z     \IEEEtag{other stuff}
\end{IEEEeqnarray}

\begin{equation} % just for checking the number has not advanced
a
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here you are, with `alignat` and `eqparbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\newcommand{\eqmathbox}[2][M]{\eqmakebox[#1]{$\displaystyle#2$}}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{3}\label{rcl-eq}
  aa & & \eqmathbox{bbbbb} & & & c \tag*{a, b and c} \\
  x & &\eqmathbox{ y} & & & zzz \tag*{other stuff}
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The `rl` alignment is not that deeply embedded in the amsmath code and so it is easy to use `alignat` (or any of the AMS alignments) with different settings. Here I provide a command that lets you specify a string such as `clr` that will be repeated as often as necessary, just like the standard `rl`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\def\align@preamble@r{%
\hfil
    \strut@
    \setboxz@h{\@lign$\m@th\displaystyle{##}$}%
    \ifmeasuring@\savefieldlength@\fi
    \set@field
    \tabskip\z@skip}
\def\align@preamble@l{%
\strut@
\setboxz@h{\@lign$\m@th\displaystyle{{}##}$}%
    \ifmeasuring@\savefieldlength@\fi
    \set@field
    \hfil
    \tabskip\alignsep@}
\def\align@preamble@c{%
\hfil
    \strut@
\setboxz@h{\@lign$\m@th\displaystyle{{}##}$}%
    \ifmeasuring@\savefieldlength@\fi
    \set@field
    \hfil
    \tabskip\alignsep@
}


\def\setalignpreamble#1{\def\align@preamble{}\x@setalignpreamble#1\relax}
\def\x@setalignpreamble#1{%
\ifx\relax#1\else
\edef\align@preamble{%
\unexpanded\expandafter{\align@preamble}%
&\span\expandafter\noexpand\csname align@preamble@#1\endcsname}%
\expandafter\x@setalignpreamble
\fi}



\begin{document}

default (rl)
\begin{alignat}{2}
  a&b&c&d\\
www& xxx&yyy&zzz
\end{alignat}

rl \setalignpreamble{rl}
\begin{alignat}{2}
  a &b&c&d\\
www& xxx&yyy&zzz
\end{alignat}

c \setalignpreamble{c}
\begin{alignat}{2}
  a &b&c&d\\
www& xxx&yyy&zzz
\end{alignat}


ccrr \setalignpreamble{ccrr}
\begin{alignat}{2}
  a &b&c&d\\
www& xxx&yyy&zzz
\end{alignat}

lcrc \setalignpreamble{lcrc}
\begin{alignat}{2}
  a &b&c&d\\
www& xxx&yyy&zzz
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I have *never* seen `##` used alone before, except in `##1` and other escaped parameters. Could you give us a concise explanation of what dark magic is at work here? Great solution by the way!

Comment: @GeorgesDupéron there is no special meaning for `##1` in tex, it is just that in definitions, `##` is replaced by `#` in just the same way as `#1` is replaced by the first argument. so `##1` if used in a definition is replaced by `#1` because `##` is replaced by `#` and `1` is just `1`.

Comment: But what is the role of this single `#` (after expansion) here? I don't see a number appended to it, and `\[\displaystyle{#}\]` (with one or two `#`) obviously produces an error. Is it part of the syntax matched by `\m@th`, or something like that?

Comment: @GeorgesDupéron that is the syntax of Tex's  `\halign` primitive that underlies all these environments using `&` a centred column is specified as `&\hfil#\hfil&` where `#` is replaced by the cell contents.

Comment: @Skillmon done.

Answer (score 2):

This is a complete kludge, that strongly depends on the height of the math involved.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tabstackengine}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
&\tag*{a, b and c}\\&{\setstackgap{L}{1\baselineskip}\setstacktabulargap{0pt}
\ensureTABstackMath{\smash{\tabularLongstack{rcl}{aa&bbbbb&cc\\x&y&z }}}}
\tag*{other stuff}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @GeorgesDupéron There were some updates in the last 6 months or so.  You can get the new `.sty` file and PDF at https://ctan.org/pkg/tabstackengine

Comment: That was it, updating `tabstackengine.sty`, `listofitems.sty` and `listofitems.tex` fixed the `Use of \\smash doesn't match its definition.` error.

Comment: @GeorgesDupéron The upgrade to using the `listofitems` parser was indeed a big upgrade.  That is a package worth investigating on its own.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a somewhat comprehensive implementation using TikZ and `overlay,remember picture` of `\tikztag{text}`.

The starred version `\tikztag*{text}` omits the parentheses surrounding `text`. When a single  optional argument is given, it gives the name of the label, e.g. `\tikztag[eq:foo]{Foo}` will place a label such that `\ref{eq:foo}` uses `Foo` as the “ref” text. When a second optional argument is given, it chooses the text for the “ref”, e.g. `\tikztag*[eq:foo][Short]{Blah blah (Short)}` will reference the equation as `Short` but will include a bit more `Blah Blah` to the right of the equation.

References made with `\ref{…}` point to the correct sub-equation when hyperref is loaded.

To use it, simply copy everything between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` in your preamble (or in an `.sty`, removing the `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` lines). Then, use `\begin{taggableequationstar}…\end{{taggableequationstar}` in place of `\begin{equation*}…\end{equation*}` for the equations containing uses of `\tikztag`.

[image: Screenshot of the resulting document.]

```
% This code is released under the CC0 license (i.e. in the Public Domain
% or under a very permissive license if your country does not recognise
% dedications to the Public Domain.
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\usepackage{amsmath, tikz, array, hyperref, lipsum}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Parse options into:
%    \if@tikztag@star
%    \if@tikztag@label@
%    \@tikztag@label
%    \if@tikztag@labeltext@
%    \@tikztag@label
\newif\if@tikztag@star@
\newif\if@tikztag@label@
\newif\if@tikztag@labeltext@
\def\tikztag{\@ifstar\@tikztag@star\@tikztag@nostar}
\def\@tikztag@star{\@tikztag@star@true\expandafter\@tikztag@common}
\def\@tikztag@nostar{\@tikztag@star@false\expandafter\@tikztag@common}
\def\@tikztag@common{\@ifnextchar[{%
    \@tikztag@label@true\@tikztag@get@label%
  }{%
    \@tikztag@label@false\@tikztag%
  }}
\def\@tikztag@get@label[#1]{\def\@tikztag@label{#1}\expandafter\@tikztag@get@maybe@labeltext}
\def\@tikztag@get@maybe@labeltext{\@ifnextchar[{%
    \@tikztag@labeltext@true\@tikztag@get@labeltext%
  }{%
    \@tikztag@labeltext@false\@tikztag%
  }}
\def\@tikztag@get@labeltext[#1]{\def\@tikztag@labeltext{#1}\expandafter\@tikztag}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Implementation:
\edef\tikztagnumber{0}
\newcommand{\@tikztag}[1]{%
  % place the marker:
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\tikztagnumber}{\tikztagnumber+1}%
  \xdef\tikztagnumber{\tikztagnumber}%
  \tikz[remember picture]\coordinate(tikztagmarker\tikztagnumber){};%
  % dispatch given the options
  \expandafter\gdef\csname @tikztag@tag@\tikztagnumber\endcsname{#1}%
  \if@tikztag@label@%
    \if@tikztag@labeltext@%
      \if@tikztag@star@%
        \edef\@@tikztag{\noexpand\@@@tikztag{\expandafter\noexpand\@tikztag@label}{\expandafter\noexpand\@tikztag@labeltext}{\expandafter\noexpand\csname @tikztag@tag@\tikztagnumber\endcsname}{\tikztagnumber}{\noexpand\@firstoftwo}}%
      \else%
        \edef\@@tikztag{\noexpand\@@@tikztag{\expandafter\noexpand\@tikztag@label}{\expandafter\noexpand\@tikztag@labeltext}{(\expandafter\noexpand\csname @tikztag@tag@\tikztagnumber\endcsname)}{\tikztagnumber}{\noexpand\@firstoftwo}}%
      \fi%
    \else%
      \if@tikztag@star@%
        \edef\@@tikztag{\noexpand\@@@tikztag{\expandafter\noexpand\@tikztag@label}{\expandafter\noexpand\csname @tikztag@tag@\tikztagnumber\endcsname}{\expandafter\noexpand\csname @tikztag@tag@\tikztagnumber\endcsname}{\tikztagnumber}{\noexpand\@firstoftwo}}%
      \else%
        \edef\@@tikztag{\noexpand\@@@tikztag{\expandafter\noexpand\@tikztag@label}{\expandafter\noexpand\csname @tikztag@tag@\tikztagnumber\endcsname}{(\expandafter\noexpand\csname @tikztag@tag@\tikztagnumber\endcsname)}{\tikztagnumber}{\noexpand\@firstoftwo}}%
      \fi%
    \fi%
  \else%
    \if@tikztag@star@%
      \edef\@@tikztag{\noexpand\@@@tikztag{no label}{no label text}{\expandafter\noexpand\csname @tikztag@tag@\tikztagnumber\endcsname}{\tikztagnumber}{\noexpand\@secondoftwo}}%
      \else%
      \edef\@@tikztag{\noexpand\@@@tikztag{no label}{no label text}{(\expandafter\noexpand\csname @tikztag@tag@\tikztagnumber\endcsname)}{\tikztagnumber}{\noexpand\@secondoftwo}}%
    \fi%
  \fi%
  \@@tikztag%
}
\newcommand{\@@@tikztag}[5]{%
  \g@addto@macro\accumulatetikztag{\@@@@tikztag{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}}%
}
% #1=label #2=label text #3=text #4=\tikztagnumber #5=\@firstoftwo or \@secondoftwo to use label or not
\newcommand{\@@@@tikztag}[5]{%
  \tikz[overlay,remember picture]%
    \node[anchor=base east, inner xsep=0pt]%
      at (tikztagmarker#4 -| current line right)%
      {#3};%
  #5{%
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture]%
      \node[anchor=base east, inner xsep=0pt]%
        at (tikztagmarker#4 -| current line left)%
        {\phantomsection\edef\@currentlabel{#2}\label{#1}};%
  }{}
}
\newenvironment{taggableequationstar}{%
  \noindent\tikz[remember picture]\coordinate(current line left){};%
  \tikz[overlay,remember picture]%
    \coordinate[xshift=\linewidth] (current line right) at (current line left){};%
  \xdef\accumulatetikztag{}%
  \begin{equation*}%
}{%
  \end{equation*}%
  \accumulatetikztag
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{R}{>{\displaystyle}r}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\displaystyle}c}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\displaystyle}l}

\lipsum[2]
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{array}{@{}R@{}C@{}L@{}}
    a&bbbbb&c  \\
    x&y&z      \\
  \end{array}
\end{equation*}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{taggableequationstar}
  \begin{array}{@{}R@{}C@{}L@{}}
    a&bbbbb&c \tikztag[eq:foo][abc]{a, b and c} \\
    x&y&z     \tikztag[eq:bar]{other stuff}\\
    x&y&z     \tikztag{more stuff}\\
  \end{array}
\end{taggableequationstar}
Foo: \ref{eq:foo}. Bar: \ref{eq:bar}. Baz: \ref{eq:baz}. Quux: \ref{eq:quux}.
\lipsum[2]
\begin{taggableequationstar}
  \begin{array}{@{}R@{}C@{}L@{}}
    \frac{a}{i}&bbbbb&c \tikztag*[eq:baz][baz]{a, b and c (baz)} \\
    x&y&z     \tikztag*[eq:quux]{other stuff 2}\\
    x&y&z     \tikztag*{more stuff 2}\\
  \end{array}
\end{taggableequationstar}

\end{document}
```

Comment: using `array` means that the entries are set in textstyle not displaystyle as is normally the case for displayed equations.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Good point. I updated the example code to use `>{\displaystyle}r` and so on.